# postgres: How to count distinct elements in array columns given a condition

Tags: arrays, postgresql, count, distinct

I have a table like the following:

```
ID     array1           array2
7333 | {615593}        | {NULL}
7333 | {2013682}       | {NULL}
7333 | {26573,1508291} | {NULL}
7333 | {1457957}       | {NULL}
7333 | {NULL}          | {1063105}
7333 | {NULL}          | {107978,408431}
```

I am looking to query all unique items for array1 and array2 for each edge_id.  For example

```
ID   array1_distinct    array2_distinct
7333 5                  3
```

I've tried something like the following

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  array1_count 
FROM (
  SELECT id,
  COUNT(DISTINCT((CASE WHEN array1 is not null THEN (select unnest(array1)b) END)) as array1_count
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY id
) totals
limit 1
```

I always get errors like "more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression" and "set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set" when trying to count elements in arrays when using unnest.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
select id, count(distinct a1) as a1, count(distinct a2) as a2
from (
    select id, unnest(array1) as a1, unnest(array2) as a2
    from t
) s
group by id
```

Comment: Awesome - not sure why I hadn't done that.  Thank you